# C# DataTable and SqlBulkCopy

Tags: c#, sql

I have a problem with my code :

```
DataTable tablePmeElement = new DataTable("PMEELEMENT");

DataColumn codeBiblioColumn = new DataColumn();
codeBiblioColumn.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
codeBiblioColumn.ColumnName = "CODEBIBLIO";
codeBiblioColumn.AllowDBNull = false;
codeBiblioColumn.DefaultValue = "";
codeBiblioColumn.MaxLength = 3;

tablePmeElement.Columns.Add(codeBiblioColumn);

element.CODEBIBLIO = (this.bibMde.BibCode.Length > 3) ? 
this.bibMde.BibCode.Substring(0, 3) : this.bibMde.BibCode;

tablePmeElement.Rows.Add(element);

s.WriteToServer(tablePmeElement);
```

When I execute this code, I get an error:

> Column: "CODEBIBLIO" contains data with a length greater than: 3.

Have you an idea to solve my problem because I didn't find any solution.

Comment: What do you think the error means?

Comment: Where's the SQL?

Comment: The SQL is generated by the SQLBulk

Comment: What's the type of the `element` object?

Comment: element object is a PMELEMENT object

Comment: @Moussawi, is it possible that your DB already contains rows that exceed max length? You only posted some isolated chunks of code here and this doesn't help as we can't see what is actually been written to server.

Answer (score 0):

When you set the `MaxLength` property on a `DataColumn`, you need to make sure the character length of the data returned for this column is under the property value. For instance, if you set `codeBiblioColumn.MaxLength = 3` and the database returns a value larger than 3 characters, you will get a run-time error. To resolve this, either increase the `MaxLength` value, or decrease the length of the values stored in your database.

Comment: Into the database, the column property is set to 3 so i set the DataColumn to 3 too.

Comment: What is the column type? And what are the values returned when you run the query in the database?

Comment: The column type is string and when i ru this query into the database, The value which is returned me is ok

Comment: But When i remove that, when I run WriteToServer method to insert this into the database the same error is returned

Comment: @Moussawi That is because you are trying to insert a value larger than 3 characters into the column

Comment: But as you can see in my code, I run a substring method for take 3 char

Comment: s.WriteToServer(tablePmeElement);

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the code in which the error is happening?